# How do I schedule tasks in react-native for all application states?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing my first mobile app ever and am learning the development and execution environment with react-native.

Simply, I want to create a task scheduler that runs every hour and only between the hours that user defines and send a very simple push notification. I want the task scheduler to be able to run when the app is open in the foreground, when the app is in the background and when the application is closed.

My solution is using this library for local push notifications: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

But i'm struggling to find a solution to schedule a task that pushes these notifications that works across all the three states mentioned above. I have found this library (https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task) for scheduling background tasks but I feel like I will need a hybrid approach with either remote notifications, like with firebase, or storing in local storage and having a timer in the app itself.

Does the community have a common pattern to achieve this use case? Thanks

Comment: I have been working on this for about 2 to 3 days and I have found that expo-taskmanager and expo background fetcher solve this for both ios and android. I will report back with a more detailed answer once I get all the kinks worked out. The idea is to use setInterval when app is open and in foreground and the expo library for when it's closed and in background.